# make div position fixed depending of its height using css

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Good day.

Please consider next simple code:

```
                <div className="box-and-clock">
                    
                        {isBoxShown && (
                            <div className="box">
                                {value}
                            </div>
                        )}
                        
                        <img
                            onMouseOver={() => setIsBoxShown(true)}
                            onMouseOut={() => setIsBoxShown(false)}
                            src={clockIcon}/>
                </div>
```

So I've got following layout (I've cut some redundant data)

[image]

When user points at the clock icon he sees some data.
The problem is when there is more data in the black box the arrow (which is done by pseudoelements) doesn't point to clock icon anymore. Something like this

[image]

I need to make that blackbox to be on certain position from the clock icon without depending on its height.

I've tried `display: table` to the parent div and `display: table-cell` to the child, but with no luck. any advices?

My css

```
.box {
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 130px;
    height: auto;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 320px;
    right: 228px;
}

.box-and-clock {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: You should post rendered HTML code and relevant CSS, otherwise there is no way to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Position the box so that the arrow always points to the icon. Allow the box to increase in height upwards.

Comment: if you wrap your image and box in the same relative div, you can give you box absolute position of bottom 100% and it will always stay above the clock

Comment: As @Paulie_D asked I've added my css

Answer (score 0):

you can set parent element with css `position: relative;` to let children identity its position, so children element can use `position: absolute;` to place itself relative to its parent's position.

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 130px;
  /* height: auto; */
  background: black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  /* top: 320px; */
  /* right: 228px; */

  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  transform: translateY(-100%); /* offset element */
}

.box-and-clock {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  position: relative; /* you need this! */
}
```

ps, for more detailed concept of css position, you may keyword search: `css position property`